# xstream - reusing the default converter in a custom converter

Tags: java, xstream

I'm using xstream to process an xml string but some fields of the object have changed between versions, so i'm implementing
a custom converter. A summary of the field changes is listed below, and only the first two field types are different.

```
Field    type1      type2
a        short      String
b        String     Object
c        List       List
d        Object     Object
.
.
.
x        String     String
```

My current converter is implemented to handle each of the fields specifically, which leads to a large number of 'else if' conditions within the unmarshal() method

```
package a.b.c.reports;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.Converter;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.MarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.UnmarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamReader;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamWriter;

public class MyConverter implements Converter {

..

@Override
public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader,UnmarshallingContext context) {

    while (reader.hasMoreChildren()) {
        reader.moveDown();
        if(reader.getNodeName().equals("a"))
        {
            a = reader.getValue();
        }
        else if (reader.getNodeName().equals("b")) 
        {
            b = (Object) context.convertAnother(reader, Object.class);
        } 
        else if(reader.getNodeName().equals("c"))
        {
            a = reader.getValue();
        }
        ..
        ..
    }
}
```

Is there a smarter way to delegate the processing of fields who's types have not changed to the default xstream converter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is a bit stale, but nevertheless took me some time to gather the bits.

Simple solution to that is to extend the `ReflectionConverter` instead of implementing the raw `Converter` interface. `ReflectionConverter` is the default converter in the XStream so override what's needed and `super` everything else. Then `new XStream().register` your new converter and you're good.

Comment: It can be registered inline like this: `xStream.registerConverter(new ReflectionConverter(xStream.getMapper(), xStream.getReflectionProvider()) { ... });` where `xs` is the `XStream` at hand.